# What's the best mobile/portable photo printer out there?

Tags: printer

I'm currently comparing [Polaroid CZA10011 PoGo Instant Mobile Printer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001APNVTQ) and [Canon SELPHY CP800 Black Compact Photo Printer (4350B001)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YL412A). I was wondering whether there's a photo printer out there that is as portable as the PoGo Mobile printer that has the quality of Selphy.

Comment: I have an HP officejet H470. I have 4 printers on my desk and as much as I love Brother printers, HP is still the go to printer for me. My H470 goes with us in our camper in the summer and is wifi if there is a network around that I can get onto. But it's so portable that hooking it up to the laptop with the cable is just not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you need to ask yourself is whether you'll be satisfied with 2" by 3" prints made on dye-incorporating paper (the ZINK technology) or whether you want larger (4" by 6") prints made with dye-sublimation technology. If you want dye sub results, the printer needs to be bigger for any given picture size, and if you want 4x6, the printer will need to be twice as big (at least in two of its dimensions) regardless of the technology.

Both Canon and Sony offer very compact 4x6 dye sub printers. The Sony is not as tall as the flat Canon, but it is a little wider (and more expensive), but neither can come anywhere near the Polaroid/ZINK printer in terms of size. But then, they're meant for printing photographs, not stickers (which is one of the primary features of the ZINK paper).

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at Zink printers. http://www.zink.com/buy-ZINK . They don't use standard paper, but it is a very good printer, and is ultra mobile.

Comment: ZINK is the same printer as the Polaroid PoGo. In an odd turnabout, Polaroid is now licensing instant photography technology from a third party. Whodathunkit?

Comment: Well, _there is no more Polaroid_. It's more accurate to say that the company which bought the brand is licensing some technology to sell under that brand.